# Help! Ajax not getting an external page content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to extract the source code of a webpage which is hosted by other website, but the problem is that O get an empty response, I tried to pull the source of multiple websites but the problem is from my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('http://www.xxxx.com', function(xdata) {
        alert("content: "+xdata);
    });
});
```

Is there any mistake?

Note: when I try to get the source of a local page, it works, but I don't know why it doesn't for an external one

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't allowed, according to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The only way to approach this is to use some server-side pull of the data, which you would then process using your AJAX requests, this is known as a [Cross-Domain Proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy).

Answer (score 0):

you cant use AJAX across domains

Comment: Is there something else similar in javascript

Comment: Bauer's answer of using a cross domain proxy is the only way

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @devundef in the 2 1\2 years since i posted this i have surely learned a lot about posting etiquette. thank you

Comment: @Pharabus, the comment is canned and posted by the review system. This comments are creating trouble because people do not know this... but ok.

Comment: Your answer was flagged by the community (or selected by the automatic system) and so it end up on the review system. You have enough points to use the review tool, take a look.

Comment: @devundef While I think reviewing old answers to clean up the system is commendable, if it's this old, you might want to consider refraining from leaving comment (just select "no comment needed"). The point of the comment is to provide some constructive feedback, but when it's this old, it's unlikely to be viewed as such. There should probably be a statute of limitations on providing canned feedback on old answers.

Comment: @Rob, you're right. I thought that the options there were like the questions flag options (ie comments for moderators not for the owner of the answer). After 5 or 10 answers I realized that...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use contain from an other domain because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

please look into [JsonP](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/).

Answer (score 0):

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header need to set on external site to do cross domain access.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the SOP (same origin policy), You can't use URL's from other domains. Try accessing a page from local server and don't use http.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in building your own proxy, there's a very easy-to-use public proxy (hosted on AppEngine) for this, with a JavaScript library.  CurlJS: http://curljs.azoffdesign.com/

Your example could be done like this (after including the library):

```
curl("http://www.xxxx.com", function (status, xdata) {
  alert("content:" + xdata);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have a server using a virtual domain and created an apache proxy.

Super fast, works, no quirks.

Copy this, fix paths (mod_proxy, domains, etc...), add to your .conf file, restart server

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/local/zend/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/local/zend/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass /datadomain http://datadomain.com/webservices
ProxyPassReverse /datadomain http://datadomain.com/webservices
```

Now http://datadomain.com/webservices/data.php = http://yourdomain.com/datadomain/data.php

Enjoy!!!